# Execution Error trying to Create two dimensional array using typedef

Tags: arrays, c

I'm getting the following error from my code:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
int checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));

warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'int' from a function with result type 'NEWTYPE' (aka 'int *'); take the address with & [-Wint-conversion]
return checkeredArray;
```

My code is below.  What have I done wrong?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int* NEWTYPE;

NEWTYPE ARRAY(int N);

int STORE(NEWTYPE as, int N, int row, int col, int val);

int FETCH(NEWTYPE as, int N, int row, int col);


NEWTYPE ARRAY(int N)
{
    int checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    //    if (checkeredArray == NULL)
    //    {
    //        printf("Malloc failed!\n");
    //        return -1;
    //    }
    return checkeredArray;
}


int STORE(NEWTYPE as, int N, int row, int col, int val)
{
    int temp;

    if ((row & 1) != (col & 1))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (row < 0 || col < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (row >= N || col >= N)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        temp = ((N * row)/2) + (col/2);
        as = as + temp;
        *as = val;

        return 1;
    }
}

int FETCH(NEWTYPE as, int N, int row, int col)
{
    if ((row & 1) != (col & 1))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (row < 0 || col < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (row >= N || col >= N)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        int temp = ((N * row) / 2) + (col / 2);

        as = as + temp;

        int val = *as;

        return val;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at this declaration  int checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int)); and reread the compiler message. After that say what is unclear with the message.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Is it because I should be declaring checkeredArray as "NEWTYPE" and not "int"

Comment: Compile with all warnings enabled and consider the warnings as errors.

Comment: @Dobby The function malloc allocates memory and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. So [pointer shall be assigned to pointer.

Comment: @Dobby Hiding a pointer type with this typedef: `typedef int* NEWTYPE;` is generally a bad idea as it usually only causes confusion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky This is a question I was assigned, and they tell you to define it that way. It has to be literally cut and pasted how they tell you.

Comment: `int checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1) / 2) * sizeof(int));` -> `NEWTYPE checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1) / 2) * sizeof(int));`. There may be other problems though, I didn't check.

Comment: Okay thanks, don't have long to solve it so I'll try my best. When I try testing my code using main it seems to work okay

Comment: _and they tell you to define it that way._ Pointer arithmetic is a feature which is provided by a few languages only (and not provided by the vast amount of others for a reason). While this gives much control and flexibility, it also requires much care for proper usage and the potential danger to write code which compiles but doesn't work. Hence, it became good style _not_ to hide pointers, so that the application programmer is warned when using them. Whoever gave you this code, IMHO didn't consider requirements for software maintainability which are important for real world programming.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the info! I'll make sure to take this into account when coding with pointers in the future. This is what they give you in the assessment, I'm still new to pointers and allocating memory address space so I'm trying to learn as I go.
```
"Declare a type abbreviation NEWTYPE:
  typedef int* NEWTYPE;
  
IMPORTANT: you must call the type exactly NEWTYPE: that is the proper name of the new type abbreviation you are introducing."
```

Answer (score 1):

At least

**wrong type declaration**

`int checkeredArray` should be a pointer, not an `int`.

```
typedef int* NEWTYPE;
NEWTYPE ARRAY(int N) {
    // int checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    NEWTYPE checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    return checkeredArray;
}
```

or change the `NEWTYPE` to an `int`

```
typedef int NEWTYPE;
NEWTYPE *ARRAY(int N) {
    // int checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    NEWTYPE *checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    return checkeredArray;
}
```

**Floating point function `floor()` not needed**

Integer math divisions truncates toward 0, discarding the fraction.

```
    // NEWTYPE checkeredArray = malloc(floor(((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    NEWTYPE checkeredArray = malloc( ((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
```

---

Also

**Allocate to the size of the referenced object, not the type.**

Easier to code right, review and maintain.
Notice the type of pointer `checkeredArray` is not important here - just that is is a pointer.

```
    // checkeredArray = malloc( ((N * N) + 1)/2) * sizeof(int));
    checkeredArray = malloc(sizeof (*checkeredArray) * ((N * N) + 1)/2));
```

**`int` vs. `size_t`**

When `int N` is large, `N * N` may overflow whereas with `size_t` math, it is less likely.

```
    // ((N * N) + 1)/2)
    (((size_t) N * N) + 1)/2)
```

or change signature.

```
// NEWTYPE ARRAY(int N)
NEWTYPE ARRAY(size_t N)
```